# Animation Blink not working properly on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css-animations

I've added a blink animation to one of the elements from my menu-bar.
It works perfectly in Mozilla, but in Chrome it stops after being clicked and only clearing the browser data helps. Sometimes even that doesn't solve it.

Can you help? It does not work on IE either, but that is not as important.

```
.menu-box #menu-item-368 a {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: blink;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -ms-animation-name: blink;
  -ms-animation-duration: 500ms;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes blink {
   from {
      color: white;
   }
   to {
      color: red;
   }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes blink {
   from {
      -webkit-color: white;
   }
   to {
      -webkit-color: red;
   }
}
 @-ms-keyframes blink {
   from {
      -ms-color: white;
   }
   to {
      -ms-color: red;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link stops blinking when the link has been clicked because the browser's default `:visited` style is being applied and most browsers limit styling of the [:visited pseudo-class.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply
>   using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color,
>   background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color,
>   border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color,
>   outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke.

To get around this you can animate the opacity of the link instead.

```css
a {
  animation: blink 500ms infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">hello world</a>
```

---

A few side notes...

My example makes use of the [short-hand animation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

I also removed the prefixes, for brevity and because most modern browsers no longer require them.

Use blinking text sparingly and with extreme caution or don't use it at all. Many users find it irritating. [The `<blink>` tag was depreciated for a good reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!

I'd like to make only the text blink, because when the whole thing blinks, it also makes the right line that separates that menu from the other blink.
Something like: ONE | TWO | THREE
If I do opacity, instead of having "ONE" blink, instead "ONE |" blinks.
I am fairly new to this, so I appreciate any input.

Comment: @DanielFriedmann You could always move the pipe character into a separate element. `<a href="">link</a><span>|</span><a href="">link</a>` for instance

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I am messing with a Wordpress Theme. Since my knowledge is not enough as to create an entire site the way I want. I understand changing these is a bit troublesome. But I can do more modifying than creating at this point.

I am not sure If I could separate the line that gets added to each new menu into a separate element. The pipe was just an example, it is not actually a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

remove the -webkit- and -ms- prefixes from the color property

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
   from {
      color: white;
   }
   to {
      color: red;
   }
}
 @-ms-keyframes blink {
   from {
      color: white;
   }
   to {
      color: red;
   }
}
```

to check if prefixes are needed check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: I removed -ms- and -webkit-. No change there.

Thanks!